# SemanticUI/ReactJS modal not support html content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I using `ReactJS` and `SemanticUI`, want to use `modal` but look like it's not support `html` inside it, right? just display plain text. well, I made a compontent for displaying modal called `Alert`:

```
<Modal
    open={this.props.open}
    size={this.props.size}
    content={this.props.content}
    actions={[
        { key: 'no', content: this.props.actions, positive: false, onClick: this.props.close }
    ]}
/>
```

In a page I display alert on click:

```
goBuy = (e) => {
    let obj = {
        size: 'tiny',
        actions: 'nope',
        click: this.goSpend,
        content: 'Are you sure?',
    }
    this.setState({
        alert: obj,
        alertOpen: true,
    })
}
```

It working fine, but now I want to add some html code in content like this:

```
content: 'Are you <b>sure</b>?',
```

But this not working and display html code like plain text and not make it bold. Any idea how can I solve this?

`Are you <b>sure</b>?`

But want this:

> Are you **sure**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to using `jsx` with `return` just go this way:

```
const someHtml = (<p>Are you <b>sure</b>?</p>);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the Modal itself thinks the value you are passing to `content` is a text value so the modal displays exact same word you have provided. So instead of passing your `<br>` tag there, you can pass jsx as a content and render it like this.

```
 const content = {
       return(<p>Are you <b>sure</b></p>);
     }
goBuy = (e) => {
    let obj = {
        size: 'tiny',
        actions: 'nope',
        click: this.goSpend,
        content: {content },
    }
    this.setState({
        alert: obj,
        alertOpen: true,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass jsx as a `content` and render it.